# Python3, MongoDB Insert only if document does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I currently have a dictionary with data being pulled from an API, where I have given each datapoint it's own variable (job_id, jobtitle, company etc.):

```
output = {
        'ID': job_id, 
        'Title': jobtitle, 
        'Employer' : company, 
        'Employment type' : emptype, 
        'Fulltime' : tid, 
        'Deadline' : deadline, 
        'Link' : webpage
}
```

that I want to add to my database, easy enough:

```
db.jobs.insert_one(output)
```

but this is all in a for loop that will create 30-ish unique new documents, with names, titles, links and whatnot, this script will be run more than once, so what I would like for it to do is only insert the "output" as a document if it doesn't already exist in the database, all of these new documents do have their own unique ID's coming from the **job_id** variable am I able to check against  that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to try two things :

**1)** Doing `.find()` & if no document found for given `job_id` then writing to DB is a two way call - Instead you can have an [unique-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html) on `job_id` field, that will throw an error if your operation tries to insert duplicate document (Having unique index is much more safer way to avoid duplicates, even helpful if your code logic fails).

**2)** If you've 30 dict's - You no need to iterate for 30 times & use `insert_one` to make 30 database calls, instead you can use [insert_many](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert_many#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) which takes in an array of dict's & writes to database.

**Note :** By default all dict's are written in the order they're in the array, in case if a dict fails cause of duplicate error then `insert_many` fails at that point without inserting rest others, So to overcome this you need to pass an option
`ordered=False` that way all dictionaries will be inserted except duplicates.

Comment: I've got insert_many working, but I can't seem to get 'job_id' working as a unique-index, getting **"pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unknown index plugin '23964927'"** as an error with: **db.jobs.create_index([('ID', job_id)], unique=True** as the code

Comment: @Derpa : I've not really worked on `pymongo` but why don't you create `unique index` on db itself ? Do you want your code to do that (which can usually do when we need to make sure an index available all the time (if an index got deleted by any change) - otherwise we can just create index once on DB & then no need to check again)?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that I understand the unique-index anymore, I thought that if I pull the data from an API, (it might be the same next week or it might be slightly different), but every post from that API has a unique ID. Wouldn't it be easier to check against that? Or is that what it does? Anyhow, doing it in the code would be nice since I'm going to do some testing and probably delete data a couple of times

Comment: @Derpa : Deletion of data doesn't delete indexes on a collection (deleting index or dropping collection/db does delete indexes). So when the same **unique ID** comes in next week with updated data then you need to merge updated with existing right ? So do you want that *or* do you just don't insert/update the new data coming next week (just ignores)?

Comment: Ey, I got it working! So instead of _db.jobs.create_index([('ID', job_id)], unique=True_ it has to be: _db.jobs.create_index([('ID', **1**)], unique=True_

Edit: Saw your comment now, either or, because the information wont change, what I would like to do later is delete the item if the date on "deadline" is passed, but that's a whole other problem

Comment: @Derpa : Yes if `ID` is your field then `1` or `-1` next to it should say index should be  incremental or decremental order, I've confused by that syntax when I correlate it with actual mongodb command I've got it now :-) So did you check my question in above comment ?

Comment: Hmm.. I think I would go with ignore in this case, because the information wont change, however, I could insert todays date into each post and later mail out the ones from "today" if the old posts get to stay how they are

Comment: @Derpa : Then the above changes should work for you, are you seeing any issues implementing give suggestions ?

Comment: Nope, it works great now! How would One merge and update with the new data? You don't have to answer that if you don't want to :) I was actually able to finish my script now, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Derpa : you need to use mongoDB’s ‘.findOneAndUpdate’ function with upsert true insert of ‘insert_many’..

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

replace

`db.jobs.insert_one(output)`

with

`db.jobs.replace_one({'ID': job_id}, output, upsert=True)`

ORIGINAL ANSWER with worked example:

Use [`replace_one()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one) with `upsert=True`. You can run this multiple times and it will with insert if the `ID` isn't found or replace if it is found. It wasn't quite what you were asking as the data is always updated (so newer data will overwrite any existing data).

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

for i in range(30):
    db.employer.replace_one({'ID': i},
    {
            'ID': i,
            'Title': 'jobtitle',
            'Employer' : 'company',
            'Employment type' : 'emptype',
            'Fulltime' : 'tid',
            'Deadline' : 'deadline',
            'Link' : 'webpage'
    }, upsert=True)

# Should always print 30 regardless of number of times run.
print(db.employer.count_documents({}))
```

Comment: So what the script does is pull some information from an API, atm it produces around 30 docs, but it might as well be 50 or 27, what I want to be able to do is run this script over and over, but only write new data if it doesn't already exist in the collection or database, so that I wont end up with duplicates of the same information in the database, the "job_id" variable pulls a unique ID from the API that belongs with the rest of the information in each document

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have explained. The code I provided was just a sample to show how it could work. All you need to do is replace `db.jobs.insert_one(output)` with  `db.jobs.replace_one({'ID': job_id}, output, upsert=True)`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @BellyBuster : This might or might not work !! If you've inserted a doc today & have done couple of updates on it, a duplicate inserting tomorrow would overwrite the entire doc with any new values or will remove the fields if by any chance they aren't present in request(majorly if same op is being done every other day)..

Comment: That is correct; if that isn't what the asker wants they will need to find a different method, e.g. the one you posted.